# Text position scaling

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I'm now using `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` for showing some charts. Depending on values of that charts (they are histograms) I change the scale. I also draw some text (they are derived from `QGraphicsItem`) for showing their values like this

[image]

But I don't scale texts like charts, so it brings to a problem. If I don't scale texts, so I get it's bounding rect's real coordinates. I want to get scale of y axis for drawing texts in right positions.

So my question how may I get the scale in `QGraphicsItem` or in `QGraphicsScene`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#scale ?

Comment: No, I tried it. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is a solution for that. In `QGraphicsScene` you can get transformation matrix like this

```
QTransform matrix = views().at(0)->transform();
```

`views()` actually returns a `QList` of `QGraphicsView`s. After getting matrix for getting scale (for example vertical) you can do this

```
qreal verticalScale = matrix.m22();
```

Difference for getting scale in `QGrapcsItem` is just

```
QTransform matrix = scene()->views().at(0)->transform();
```

And the rest is same.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement your own function for scaling, then there is not a direct way for getting scale in `QGraphicsItem`. You can make a static variables in `QGraphicsView` (where you count scale) for scales and static functions for getting them.